# do not use method if zero in

Tags: java, arrays, methods, calling-convention

I need help figuring out how to not call the method firstPosition if method occurs return zero.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SearchArray 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] numbers = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,2,4,6,8,10,1,3,5,7,9};
        int searchValues;
        int value;
        int position;

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number between 1 and 10: ");
        searchValues = keyboard.nextInt();

        value = occurs(searchValues, numbers);
        position = firstPosition(searchValues, numbers);


        System.out.println(searchValues + " occurs " + value + " times, the           first occurence" + " is at position " + (position + 1));


    }
    public static int occurs (int searhValue, int[] numbers)
    {
        int searchValues = 0; 

        for (int i = 0; i<numbers.length; i++)
        {
            if(searhValue == numbers[i])
            searchValues++; 
        }
        return searchValues;
    }
    public static int firstPosition (int searchValue, int[] numbers)
    {
        int i;

        for (i=0; i<numbers.length; i++)
        {
            if(searchValue == numbers[i])
            return i;       
        }
        return -1;
    }

}
```

//I'm pretty sure it is something simple that I am missing but I can't seem to //figure it out. 
//Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Got something against if (value !=0) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent calling `firstPosition` if there is no element matched the input value, you must check it after you call `occurs`:

```
    value = occurs(searchValues, numbers);
    System.out.println(searchValues + " occurs " + value + " time(s)");
    if (value > 0) {
        position = firstPosition(searchValues, numbers);

        System.out.println("The first occurence" + " is at position " + (position + 1));
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! it worked perfectly!